# Cargar modelos y controladores en archivo externo en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola tengo una aplicación web la cual estoy haciendo la api y necesito obtener los métodos que están en CodeIgniter pero no encuentro la manera de cargar todo lo realizado en CodeIgniter... mil gracias por su ayuda

Comment: salvo que haya rutas personalizadas por lo general es `example.com/class/function/id/`  -> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#uri-routing

Comment: Creería que le llegarías por la ruta, dependiendo lo que devuelvan tus métodos allí te las arreglas, has tus pruebas y si tienes inconvenientes publica un ejemplo para poder ilustrar un poco